# Typescript infer the returned array type elements

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: '',
}

type keysType = keyof(typeof data);

function getKeysValues(...keys: keysType[]) {
  return keys.map(k => data[k]);
}

const value = getKeysValues('id', 'name');
```

The type of `value` is `(string | number)[]`. How can I change it to be dynamic based on the passed keys? So, in the above case I'm expecting the type to be `[number, string]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mapped types on tuples [TypeScript 3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html)

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: '',
}

type Data = typeof data;
type DataKeysType = keyof(typeof data);
type DataFieldType<T> = T extends DataKeysType ?  Data[T] : never;

type MappedDataTuple<T extends DataKeysType[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: DataFieldType<T[K]>;
}

function getKeysValues<T extends DataKeysType[]>(...keys: T): MappedDataTuple<T> {
  return <any>keys.map(k => data[k]);
}

// const value: [number, string]
const value = getKeysValues('id', 'name');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works perfectly. There is an option also to infer the return type to an object instead of array? like { id: number, name: string }

Comment: Yes, it is. See Pick type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to Pick but it's still a tuple of objects.

Comment: type DataFieldType<S, T> = T extends keyof State ?  Pick<S, T> : never;

type MappedDataTuple<S, T extends (keyof S)[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: DataFieldType<S, T[K]>;
}

Comment: Actually I only need this: pick<K extends keyof S>(...keys: K[]): Pick<S, K>

Comment: So use Pick as return type, you don't need DataFieldType, MappedDataTuple

Comment: Thanks, can you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956918/typescript-create-a-dynamic-tuple-from-return-callback-function-value

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go:

```
function getKeysValues(...keys: Array<keyof typeof data>): Array<typeof data[keyof typeof data]> {
    return keys.map(k => data[k]);
}
```

You may also add generics:

```
function getKeysValues<K extends keyof typeof data>(...keys: Array<K>): Array<typeof data[K]> {
    return keys.map(k => data[k]);
}
```

But for convenience in any of the above cases I would type-aliased the `typeof data`

```
type Data = typeof data;
// then
function getKeysValues(...keys: Array<keyof Data>): Array<Data[keyof Data]>;
// or
function getKeysValues<K extends keyof Data>(...keys: Array<K>): Array<Data[K]>;
```