# Typescript create a dynamic tuple from return callback function value

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
    class A<S> {
      data?: S;

      getSomething<R extends ((data: S) => R)>(...funcs: ((data: S) => R)[]): ReturnType<R>[] {
         return <any>funcs.map(f => {
            return f(this.data as S);
         });
      }
    }

const a = new A<{ id: number, name: string }>();
const arr = a.getSomething(data => data.name, data => data.id);
```

The type of value is `unknown[]`. How can I change it to be dynamic based on the return callback values? So, in the above case I'm expecting the type to be [number, string].

Comment: You say "The type of value is `unknown[]`," but I don't see anything called `value`. Did you mean `arr`?

Comment: I'm interested, what is your use case?

Comment: @NailAchmedzhanov an internal library that needs this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your type parameter should be an array of those functions. This will enable you to capture the types of the passed in arrow functions as a tuple of functions. We can then use a mapped type to map the tuple to the appropriate return types.

```
type ReturnTypes<T extends Array<(...a: any[]) => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
}
class A<S> {
    data?: S;

    getSomething<R extends Array<((data: S) => any)>>(...funcs: R): ReturnTypes<R> {
        return <any>funcs.map(f => {
            return f(this.data as S);
        });
    }
}

const a = new A<{ id: number, name: string }>();
const arr = a.getSomething(data => data.name, data => data.id); //[string, number]
```

**Edit**

You can also use an array as a parameter, but you need to change the constraint a bit in order to get the compiler to infer a tuple type:

```
type ReturnTypes<T extends Array<(...a: any[]) => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
}
class A<S> {
    data?: S;

    getSomething<R extends [(data: S) => any] | Array<(data: S) => any>>(funcs: R): ReturnTypes<R> {
        return <any>funcs.map(f => {
            return f(this.data as S);
        });
    }
}

const a = new A<{ id: number, name: string }>();
const arr = a.getSomething([data => data.name, data => data.id]); //[string, number]
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a way to accept an array? `getSomething([data => data.name, data => data.id])`

Comment: @undefined Yes, but you need to change the constraint a bit to make the compiler infer a tuple type. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.

Comment: This is so complicated. You should make a video or article about these advanced types.

Comment: @undefined I keep planning to, but 2 small kids, also a job .. time is not my friend :(

Comment: Lol. Thanks for all the help. You are a typescript master.