# Typescript generics: Return array type to match input array by position with mapped types

Tags: typescript, generics

I've got a function to get values from a buffer by datatype (e.g. U8, U16, F32, String, etc). I'm trying to figure out how to type the function so that,for example, if I pass in `['u8','u16','u16','string']` the inferred return type would be `[number,number,number,string]`. I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947620/typescript-infer-the-returned-array-type-elements) and followed the same pattern, but cannot get the result I need.

Here's the relavent portion of the code:

```
type BytesTypeMap = {
  U8: number,
  U16: number,
  U32: number,
  String: string,
  Text: string,
}
export type BytesType = keyof BytesTypeMap;
type BytesTypeMapped<T> = T extends BytesType ?  BytesTypeMap[T] : never;
type BytesTypeArray<T extends BytesType[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: BytesTypeMapped<T[K]>;
}

export class MessageBuffer {

  read<T extends BytesType[]>(types:T):BytesTypeArray<T>{
    return types.map(type=>{
      const method = `read${type}` as const;
      return this[method](); // Typescript error: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'BytesTypeArray<T>'
    });
  }

  // ... methods matching those created with the template string above...
}

// GOAL
// ... create an instance of the class, etc.
messageBufferInstance.read(["U8","U16","String"]);
// Inferred response type should be [number,number,string]
// but is instead (number|string)[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is not smart enough to understand that how `map()` converts a generic tuple of one type to a tuple of a mapped type inside the implementation of `read()`.  The [standard library's typing for the `Array.prototype.map()` method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6643d973856d89ef9f2e85e46fe5e460503ff256/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1349) is

```
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

which only maps arrays-to-arrays and not tuples-to-tuples... and especially not tuples-of-`BytesType`-to-tuples-of-related-`BytesTypeMapped`.  And such a signature would be so specific to this particular call of `map()` that even trying to come up with it and [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) it into the `Array` interface would be wasted effort.

Instead, I recommend accepting that the compiler is not up to the task of verifying type safety here, by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to explicitly tell the compiler that you are taking responsibility for the types being correct:

```
read<T extends BytesType[]>(types: [...T]): BytesTypeArray<T> {
  return types.map((type: BytesType) => {
    const method = `read${type}` as const; // assuming we're using TS4.1+
    return this[method]();
  }) as BytesTypeArray<T>;
}
```

Notice how we are returning that `as BytesTypeArray<T>`. It's close enough to `(string | number)[]`.

Aside: I don't think `` ​`read${type}` as const `` will work before TS4.1 introduces [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707).  That's coming out soon so I'll leave it.

So that takes care of the implementation side of the function.  Now to the caller's side:

---

The other piece of this is getting

```
const resp = messageBufferInstance.read(["U8", "U16", "String"]);
```

to be inferred as `[number, number, string]` and not `(string | number)[]`.  We can get that to happen by changing the `read()` method signature to give the compiler a *hint* that `T` should be a tuple if possible instead of being widened to an array when you call `read()`.

There are different ways to do this, and before TS 4.0 introduced [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html), you had to do it this way (see [microsoft/TypeScript#27179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179))

```
// read<T extends BytesType[] | [BytesType]>(types: T): BytesTypeArray<T> {
```

where `T`'s constraint featured a tuple type, but now you can do it like this:

```
read<T extends BytesType[]>(types: [...T]): BytesTypeArray<T> {
```

where the `types` parameter is a variadic tuple spread from `T`.  Either way should work from the caller's perspective:

```
const resp = messageBufferInstance.read(["U8", "U16", "String"]);
resp[0].toFixed(); // okay
resp[2].toUpperCase(); // okay
```

I prefer the `[...T]` method because it is easier on the implementation side.

---

Okay, so both the caller and the implementation should work as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201112#code/C4TwDgpgBAQiwQM4BVwQLIEMxQLxQG8AoKKAVQA4AuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaE8gRgDYaDFuy6kyAZgBMgpq07cAysDYBLWgHMaiZWvWioyCAA9gWnRq4BfIsbAB7NsCihIseElSv8Aawgg7AGZuCChoWGAA3EQu0HAhnhjYkAAmADzIAHx4BlDGCLTJiMEeaFAA-MWhkOEA2sgAulCCEABu7FExlQkAgmxsmCDpuSYQBUVxJZA19Vn4xKQ1ANJQalC+-kENNBNViWAp6UszUdY2RvaOUADGADaYiEXoSIiY6hAw9AEB7ITcAPR-KBsCCYNLIYb5QpdNDTKAAHygNR2CRmAAoYogaMgAJTbdy7Xr9QaZX6kYGgoZ5UZQ5EwtEYmg1AB0LIauOhkEJA3SWXmpCBEGA9DYtGcaEQTMY2FR6LQ2LwvO4-Oudlo2igjEFAAs7MlsgADcnJAAkBBiln1UHuKrVwCiyrJguFouAWpUiBqmtduvqqOx9v5lnl1tpnL63MyAdOpGSEFumGBAtBlBofoVdFk7W4sfjiaNZH4qfluCyQjkAZzdzzIOSEmkUDTJYzwjYFbjVegRqUqg0RfT2h76jbuc7NcMJj7TYHuhORErCegV1V6s1D1e70+3zYAElbZhaFcIDQnmu3h8vlmiEvbQLEDh8KuXmfN+xd9p94emUbUTUAESUX8OCgf9+EA4Du10X96n9IhgTvGoAAZ6iZYA7AAMRUIwIGSP0IigAEoDsbwBlgpAwBqSRkNQsh9nYABhe4IFw-DASIgYgA)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! That's kinda what I had figured, but I was struggling to get the type assertion right. I was trying to do on the return inside the `.map()` instead of for the whole statement.